# Stuck with self-referencing linked server - will replacing the primary server name be better?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

A vendor app uses 4-part names to reference objects.  I am pushing back on that, but the current version is what it is.  We installed the app using a SQL Alias for all the good reasons you do that, but the app had tons of errors because its four part references were starting with the alias instead of the local server name.  Defining the alias on the db server had no effect - the references were being made within the DBEngine.

To get around the errors, I added a second server definition (linked server) named after the alias that referred back to the same DBEngine.  I recently heard about the performance costs of linked servers (e.g. no caching) and about how bad an idea it is to define a linked server that refers to the local server.

I am stuck with this version of the app for now, so I cannot do anything about the four-part references and cannot reinstall without the alias (my client is not willing to pay for that work).

Would it help to delete the default server definition and replace it with the alias name instead of the machine name.

Comments? Warnings? Risks? Will doing that avoid the performance issues associated with self-referencing linked servers?

As a secondary question, I would be interested in a clear explanation of why four part names are a bad idea - something I can pass on to the vendor.

Comment: If you're not getting buy-in from the customer to fix this mess, I'd leave the linked server as is. If they complain about performance, you have a really good excuse.

Comment: A SQL Alias  is not a DNS or CNAME. The issue is that upon install, the app was given the SQL Alias name (say "x") as the db server name.  The app installer then stored that name somewhere such that calls within the DBEngine (perhaps RPCs) are refererring to database objects as x.mydatabase.myschema.myobject.  Because the Windows server (and thus the SQL Server) is named "y", the object is not found.   By creating a linked server named "x" that connects to the actual server "y", the reference becomes valid, the object is found and the app works.

Comment: Randolph, I am wondering if making "x" the original server name in sys.servers would improve performance and avoid the costs and limitations of making queries through linked servers.  I assume that the use of 4-part references in itself is not a problem.  If it is a problem, please explain why.

Comment: hot2use, the alias is defined on a separate app server and uses TCP/IP.  SQL browser is disabled so the SQL Alias also injects a custom port.  I did not try creating a SQL Alias on the db server because the code that is running is running within the DBEngine, so it would have no reason to access the native client on the database server.

Comment: hot2use, the SQL Alias does not reference a CNAME. It references the Windows machine name of the database server.  Segment 1 of the 4 part name is the SQL Alias name.   Alias name=x, server=y, instance=SS1201, port=12345.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the app vendor would make you reinstall the app simply to point to a different database server; have you checked with them where the server name is stored, to see if that setting can be changed? Alternately, could you create a CNAME for the DB server that matches the alias name expected? From the application's point of view, if there's a CNAME `x` for server `y`, then it's the same as if the server's name was `x`.

Comment: OK. I have been confused.  I see that the linked server goes out to SQL Native Client then uses the alias name to come back in and uses TCP/IP.  Any suggestions on how to better make the four-part names work?  (e.g. should have specified named pipes or shared memory?)

Answer (score 1):

A linked server even if it links to itself is still a linked server with all of the pain points that entails (as you outlined in your question). I would either stand up a new server/instance with the name that you had installed and run the database there without the linked server, or get the app to reinstall with the actual server name.

Having an Alias does make things simpler - mainly that you can move the database around without the app knowing - but if it's going to do every query through a linked server then benefit is outweighed (in my opinion) by the cost.